# Erlang: Chat server crashing on startup

Tags: erlang

I got a set of tests that the program should pass and all the local tests works just fine with my server it's when I try to run the remote tests that the server crashes.

The crash message is the following:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 23-Jul-2015::23:59:17 === Error in process <0.39.0> on
node 'nodeS@127.0.0.1' with exit value: 
{undef,[{genserver,start,[server, {server_st,[],[]},#Fun<server.loop.2>],[]}]}
```

My start-up function looks as following:

```
loop(St, {From, Nick, connection_wanted}) ->
    case lists:keymember(Nick, 2, St#server_st.users) of
        false -> {ok, St#server_st{users = St#server_st.users ++ [{From, Nick}]}};
        true -> {{user_already_connected, St}, St}
    end;
```

With the record "server_st" is defined as:

```
-record(server_st, {users = [], channels = []}).
```

Finally the genserver start&loop function is:

```
start(Name, State, F) ->
Pid = spawn(fun() -> loop(State, F) end),
register(Name, Pid),
Pid.

loop(State, F) ->
receive
{request, From, Ref, Data} ->
    case catch(F(State, Data)) of
    {'EXIT', Reason} ->
        From!{exit, Ref, Reason},
        loop(State, F);
    {R, NewState} ->
        From!{result, Ref, R},
        loop(NewState, F)
    end;
{update, From, Ref, NewF} ->
    From ! {ok, Ref},
    loop(State, NewF);
stop ->
    true
end.
```

Then genserver functions I'm not allowed to change. If needed I can post the whole testsuite too.

**Edit**
Digging a bit further into the test cases and I'm unsure if it really is the server that's causing the issue, my remote connect function looks as following:

```
loop(St, {connect, {_Server, _Machine}}) ->
ServerPID = {list_to_atom(_Server), list_to_atom(_Machine)},
case genserver:request(ServerPID, {self(), St#cl_st.nick, connection_wanted}) of
    ok -> {ok, St#cl_st{connected_to = ServerPID}};
    _ -> {{error, user_already_connected, "A user with the nick " ++ St#cl_st.nick ++ "is already connected to" ++ _Server}, St}
end;
```

**Edit 2**
Found the specific row inside the testsuite that's causing the error:

```
-define(HOST, '127.0.0.1').

new_client(Nick, GUIName) ->
ClientName = test_client:find_unique_name("client_"),
ClientAtom = list_to_atom(ClientName),

% Row below is causing the error
Result = slave:start(?HOST, ClientAtom),

assert_ok("start client node "++ClientName, element(1,Result)),
ClientNode = element(2,Result),

InitState = client:initial_state(Nick, GUIName),
Result2 = spawn(ClientNode, genserver, start, [ClientAtom, InitState, fun client:loop/2]),
assert("client startup "++ClientName, is_pid(Result2)),

{Nick, ClientAtom, ClientNode}.
```

Comment: From the error `{undef,[{genserver,start,[server, {server_st,[],[]},#Fun<server.loop.2>],[]}]}`?  the function `genserver:start` is undefined.You need check if you load the module `genserver`?

Comment: @BlackMamba Hmm, in which module do I need to check that? Also by load you mean if it's included?

Comment: in you erl shell use `genserver:module_info().`.

Comment: @BlackMamba It's not from what I can tell but all other testsuites works just fine with the exact same genserver, it's just the remote tests that doesn't work for me. Also I borrowed a friends implementation which works fine with all the testsuites so I'm quite confident it's either my Server code or Client code that is the problem.

Edit: The specific error message i got when I entered "genserver:module_info()." was: "exception error: undefined function genserver:module_info/0"

Comment: you can use `nl(genserver).` in your erl shell.

Comment: @BlackMamba Just gives me "error". The specific row that's causing the crash(as far as I can track it) is in one of the tests, when "slave:start(?HOST, ClientAtom)," is called in the function that creates a new client the server crashes for some reason.

Comment: @DavidS: Your client is not starting your server, isn't it? The error report you shown is not server crash report. It is a report from the process which calls `genserver:start/3`. You did not show us the code which calls it.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil I posted the specific function that's causing the error in my original post, see the second edit.

Comment: This line causes error `Result2 = spawn(ClientNode, genserver, start, [ClientAtom, InitState, fun client:loop/2])`. Try insert `genserver:module_info(),` before line with `Result = slave:start(?HOST, ClientAtom),` I suspect the slave is running in embeded mode.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil Same result, also how do you know it's the "Result2" line that's the issue? Either way I'm not allowed to edit the testsuite and like I mentioned earlier I got a friend that manage to get it to work without modifying the testsuite.

Comment: @DavidS: You wrote 21 hours ago: _The specific error message i got when I entered "genserver:module_info()." was: "exception error: undefined function genserver:module_info/0"_ It means the module `genserver` can't be loaded even in shell. It contradict your _all other testsuites works just fine with the exact same genserver_ I am confused. There must be something different with VM parameters or configuration.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil Sorry I haven't answered in a while, was away. None of the tests is run directly from the VM. They are run through the command prompt with params, this is for one of the local test suites: ""C:/Program files/Erlang 6.2/bin/erl.exe" +P 1000000 -eval "cover:compile_directory(), eunit:test(test_client), halt()""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, was in a completely unrelated part where the client is communicating with other users. Still used the whereis command to locate other users from an older version of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `genserver:start/3` is most probably not exported or module `genserver` is not available at the node where you run code which calls it.

Comment: It is exported and all my other testsuites works with genserver, just not my remote testsuite.